# How to make this RegExp less greedy?

Tags: regular-expressions

I use `visual-regexp` to make query regexp search. Consider this text:

[image]
`\enquote{\Large{text1}} \enquote{\Large{text2}} \enquote{\Large{text3}} \enquote{\Large{text4}}`

I want regexp to match every and single macro group (the 4 groups). I invoke a query regexp by `C-c q` and entered this regexp:

`\(\\Large{\)\(.?+\)\(}\)\(}\)`

Problem is that it returned one match instead of 4 matches:
[image]

the `\(.?+\)` was very greedy to match all 4 macro groups.

But, when I get each of the 4 groups in its own line I get the desired effect:
[image]

Now I could do replace with: `\2\4` to get the desired result:
[image]

So what I was missing when all were on the same line?

Plus, can you please recommend any good documentation on using regexp/grep in Emacs?

Comment: You should use `.+?` and not `.?+`..

Comment: Yep. that solved it! feel free to upgrade your comment to an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use non greedy `+` like `\(\\Large{\)\(.+?\)\(}\)\(}\)` (note the inversion of the `?` and the `+`) if you add a `?` after a `+` the `+` will match the smaller match possible. Note also that `.?+` is the same as `.*`

Answer (score 4):

You want to match "Large, opening brace, anything but a closing brace, the closing brace".  This is the corresponding regexp

```
"\\\\Large{[^}]*}"
```

Note the regexp would be more complicated if the argument of `\Large` has groups (i.e. braces) itself.  TeXnical note: `\Large` is a declaration, must not be used as a command with arguments.

`re-builder` is very handy to practice regexp searches.

Regarding the documentation, the starting point is the Elisp manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions (or `(info "(elisp)Regular expressions")` in Emacs)

Comment: @doctorate  There are different syntaxes for regexps, some with more `\`s, some with less.  `re-builder` is just to write a regexp, not to search & replace (I haven't said that).  Which group do you want to replace?  The argument of `\Large`?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: `"\\\\Large{.+?}"` is a shorter version though.